# Is it safe to strip a shared library after linking?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, strip

Let's suppose that I got `lib.so`, I compile the binary `mySoft` and I link this to `lib.so`.

At this point, considering that everything is working as expected, It's safe or not to take `lib.so` and strip it with `strip -s lib.so` ?

To be clear I'm not interested on linking other binaries to my `lib.so` after `mySoft` is properly generated, I'm only interested on keep `mySoft` working and gain some disk space and maybe a small edge in terms of performances.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. `strip` only removes symbols that are not needed (because they have already been linked). Those symbols are useful for debugging, but they are never needed just for executing the code.

Comment: thanks, i forgot to add the part about static libraries, but I suppose that it's safe to strip the entire binary in this case.